# Balls with different colors put in a box, what is the chance that 2 picked balls have a different color?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A bucket contains $2$ red, $3$ white and $4$ blue balls. If you randomly pick(without putting the balls back) $2$ balls, how great is the chance that the picked balls have different colors?

I really don't know how to get started on this.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: compute the probability you got two balls of the same colour for each possible colour.

Comment: **Thanks for the hint mau, it really helped me so much!**  
Chance of picking 2 red balls: 2/9*1/8 = 2/72.  
Chance of picking 2 white balls: 3/9*2/8 = 6/72.  
Chance of picking 2 blue balls: 4/9*3/8 = 12/72.  
Total: = 20/72. 

Negation: 1-total= 52/72.

Answer (score 0):

D stands for different colour. Then you have the possibilities RD,WD and BD.
(B=blue et cetera).